# .remove function not working with an 'if' check in lists

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm fairly new to programming and python itself- I'm trying to use the `.remove` function to delete an item from a list if it exists in that list (as to not get the nameError).

```
q = ["cat","dog","fish","hamster","horse"]

#Request element name to delete from queue
removeElement = input("Please type in the element name to remove from the queue: ")
#Remove the given element from the list
q.remove(removeElement) if 'removeElement' in q else None

print(q)
```

Unfortunately, if I try and use the 'if' checker it the item isn't removed from my list- why is this and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Well, the string `'removeElement'` isn't in `q`, so the `.remove` method isn't being called at all. Presumably you want to check if the variable `removeElement` is in `q`.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes.. that's exactly what I wanted to do, pretty dumb mistake on my part, thanks a lot for pointing it out  :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the variable's name not a string:

```
q.remove(removeElement) if removeElement in q else None
```

Comment: Yep, that's all it was, thanks a bunch for your help  :)